# C# - Power BI Client / API - Rename Power BI workspaces with service principal

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, powerbi

I have the customer requirement to rename Power BI workspaces with my programm.

So I wrote this simple method in C# to do it:

```
public void RenameWorkspace(Guid workspaceId, string workspaceName)
{            
    var group = PowerBIClient.Groups.GetGroupAsAdmin(workspaceId);          
    group.Name = workspaceName;           

    PowerBIClient.Groups.UpdateGroupAsAdmin(workspaceId, group);
}
```

To access Power BI, I'm using a service principal:

- I created an azure app registration
- Added the service principal to a security group
- Updated the Power BI tenancy settings to allow the new security group to run Power BI APIs
- Updated the Power BI tenancy settings to allow the new security group to run Power BI Admin read-only APIs
- Granted access to the workspace to the security group and service principal

All these settings result in me being able to run the "GetGroupAsAdmin" method and get the group back. But as soon as I want to execute the method "UpdateGroupAsAdmin", I get every time a unauthorized result.

[image]

Does anyone know what setting is needed to execute the UpdateGroupAsAdmin Methode with a service principal?

As an additional note, using the same service principal, this project creates workspaces, adds users, and generates embed tokens. All without permission issues.

Comment: Did you granted something to the service principal? It should have none - `When running under service prinicipal authentication, an app must not have any admin-consent required premissions for Power BI set on it in the Azure portal.`

Comment: I tried both, granted nothing to the principal and granted all available scopes to principal. Does not change anything.